# How to move an object within the same S3 bucket using boto client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I cant seem to find a function that can move a S3 object within the same bucket. I know there's other ways other than s3 client but I need to use S3 client in this case.

Comment: There is no move method in S3. You have to copy, and then delete the old object.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the files within the s3 bucket using the s3fs module instead of boto3.

```
import s3fs
path1='s3:///bucket_name/folder1/sample_file.pkl'
path2='s3:///bucket_name/folder2/sample_file.pkl'

s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem()

s3.move(path1,path2)
```

In case if you have credentials, you could pass within the client_kwargs of S3FileSystem as shown below:

```
import s3fs
path1='s3:///bucket_name/folder1/sample_file.pkl'
path2='s3:///bucket_name/folder2/sample_file.pkl'

credentials= {}
credentials.setdefault("region_name", r_name) # mention the region
credentials.setdefault("aws_access_key_id", a_key) # mention the access_key_id
credentials.setdefault("aws_secret_access_key", s_a_key) # mention the secret_access_key

s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem(client_kwargs=credentials)

s3.move(path1,path2)
```